# Multiple canvas created from fields_for loop not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a form with a fields_for and I need a canvas for each `ff.object.print_location.id`

**Here's the entire form with fabric canvas:**

```
<%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>

  <%= ff.object.print_location.title %>
...
...
...
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-beta.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <label title="Add a background" class="myFile2%>"><span class="mdi mdi-image"> Add Background</span>
           <input type="file" id="file2-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>" />
        </label>
        <label title="Add an image" class="myFile"><span class="mdi mdi-image"> Add Photo</span>
           <input type="file" id="file-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>" />
        </label>
        <a id="lnkDownload-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>" title="Save"><span class="mdi mdi-download"> Save</span></a>
        <canvas id="fCanvas-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

        <script>

          var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>');

          var myImage = document.createElement('canvas');

          document.getElementById('file-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
             var file = e.target.files[0];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function(f) {
                var data = f.target.result;
                fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
                   var oImg = img.set({
                      left: 0,
                      top: 0,
                      angle: 0,
                      border: '#000',
                   }).scale(0.2);
                   canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                   //var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                      format: 'png',
                      quality: 1
                   });
                });
             };
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });

          document.getElementById('file2-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
             var file = e.target.files[0];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function(f) {
                var data = f.target.result;
                fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
                   // add background image
                   canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                      scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
                      scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
                   });
                });
             };
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });


             // Download
          var imageSaver = document.getElementById('lnkDownload-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>');
          imageSaver.addEventListener('click', saveImage, false);

          function saveImage(e) {
             this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                quality: 0.8
             });
             this.download = 'custom-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>.png'
          }

        </script>
```

When I do this ^, The canvas's appear for each print_location but I am unable to upload an image to all (only works on the last canvas in the loop and all file upload inputs get put into the last canvas from the loop.

Ex: If i upload a file for the first (second, or fourth. etc.) canvas, it will appear in the last one) and have it appear.

**When I use:**

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>');

const myImage = document.createElement('canvas');
```

...The canvas works as it should but only for the first print_location and none of the others.

There are a total of 6 print_locations to iterate through.

What is stopping the file/image from appearing in the canvas when using var within the fields_for loop?

What can I do to allow his to work?

Here is a codepen of this working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YmEGyW

Attempt (removed file-2 and download to simply it just to see if i can get the canvas to work alone then apply it):

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas');

  document.querySelectorAll('[id$=file-']).forEach((fileInput) => {
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
      let id = this.id.replace('file-','');
      let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas-'+id);

      // the rest of your "change" code
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(f) {
         var data = f.target.result;
         fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
               left: 0,
               top: 0,
               angle: 0,
               border: '#000',
            }).scale(0.2);
            // canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
            canvas.add(oImg);

            //var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
               format: 'png',
               quality: 1
            });
         });
      };
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the scripts on each iteration of the loop. Add it once outside the loop but do something like...

```
// add the 'change' eventListener to all elements with id starting with "file-"
document.querySelectorAll('[id$=file-']).forEach((fileInput) => {
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    let id = this.id.replace('file-','');
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas-'+id);

    // the rest of your "change" code

  })
})

// do something similar for inputs with id starting with "file2-"
```

The problem with your loop is that you are using the same names everywhere, with "var" you are replacing the previous with the new ones (that's why it only works for the last element), with "const" you are preventing the variables to change it's assignment (that's why it only works for the first one, and your browser console surelly has some errors).

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Am i removing the `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas-<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>');` and removing all `<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>` from the script (i asssume this is obvious but want to make sure)?

Comment: Added the attempt i made at the bottom.  I'm kind of lost on how this work and I'm sure it does I just not implemtnig it correctly.  Anytime I want toloop javascript, I do what i did on my first attempt and usually works

Comment: Check the browser console, you surelly have some errors there to guide you. I'm just giving you a general idea of what to do (move the code outside the loop and use querySelectorAll to target the inputs) but your code is too long and complex to suggest a concrete solution. Read stackoverflow guidelines, you need to provide a minimal example to reproduce your problem. I've seen your questions and you usually just copypaste A LOT of code and it makes it almost impossible to answer. Usually, if you try to reduce your code to the minimal, you'll probably find the answer yourself.